# Java swt tree padding

Tags: java, tree, swt, eclipse-rcp

I am able to add padding to the left of treeitems, but i don't know how to add padding to the top and bottom of the treeitems.

I want to increase/decrease the padding of tree items. This padding should be top and below not right and left

Comment: What do you mean by padding? I already mentioned changing the row height in your previous question. To do anything beyond standard you will have to draw the tree yourself with EraseItem/MeasureItem/PaintItem - or for the easier to use TreeViewer use OwnerDrawLabelProvider or one of its many subclasses.